Building project with Bazel, keep running into problems with dependencies
I'm facing difficulties trying to build one of Google's Git repos (more specifically: https://github.com/google/fhir-examples). This repo is using Bazel as a build tool, which I am not familiar with.
I managed to set up Bazel in the local directory and tried building the project but kept running into problems.
Using bazels error messages I had to make adjustemts to the WORKSPACE file, loading different components for Bazel (protobuf, bazel_skylib, rules_cc, etc...)
What I ended up doing was adding those repos piece by piece, hoping that at some point I would be able to build the entire project. However, the latest error message is asking for "'@@proto_bazel_features//:features.bzl" which I cannot find a corresponding repo for anywhere.
Also, it should probably not be that hard to simply compile a repo using Bazel which makes me think I am probably missing something basic.
Here's the last error message (the previous ones looked like this, with the other previously missing repos respectively)

Error computing the main repository mapping: at C:/users/gdo/_bazel_gdo/mn7tvmwp/external/rules_jvm_external/defs.bzl:23:6: at C:/users/gdo/_bazel_gdo/mn7tvmwp/external/rules_jvm_external/private/rules/pom_file.bzl:1:6: at C:/users/gdo/_bazel_gdo/mn7tvmwp/external/rules_java/java/defs.bzl:16:6: at C:/users/gdo/_bazel_gdo/mn7tvmwp/external/protobuf/bazel/java_lite_proto_library.bzl:9:6: at C:/users/gdo/_bazel_gdo/mn7tvmwp/external/protobuf/bazel/private/java_lite_proto_library.bzl:13:6: at C:/users/gdo/_bazel_gdo/mn7tvmwp/external/protobuf/bazel/common/proto_info.bzl:3:6: Every .bzl file must have a corresponding package, but '@@proto_bazel_features//:features.bzl' does not have one. Please create a BUILD file in the same or any parent directory. Note that this BUILD file does not need to do anything except exist.

Can anyone give me an idea on how to set it up properly?
Best

bazel --version
